# Как rollover эффектом повлиять на другие элементы?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Привет.

Есть несколько дивов, и они расположены друг над другом. Двое из дивов - элементы слайд шоу, один из дивов - убирающийся(сейчас) логотип. Так как лого находится над слоями слайд шоу, то нижние слои не реагируют на наведение мыши (а должны).

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы при наведении на `my_top_slider` двигались бы (не сами, а фоны) слои слайдшоу?

```
<div id="logo_for_my_slider"></div>
<div id = "bg_bottom_my_slider"></div>
<div id="my_top_slider"></div>
<div id="cont_my_slider">
<p style="display:block; width:100px;">
<b>Новость Номера</b><br>
нет, ну вы представляете:<br>
<a href="#">Под землею, город строят</a>
</p>
</div>
```

и

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // bg - фоновый элемент
    // bgFade - затеняющий элемент
    // period - время между сменами изображений
    // fadeTime - время на смену изображения
    // images - адреса изображений

    function fadeInOutLoop(bg, bgFade, period, fadeTime, images) {

        var fadeIn = true;
        var imageIndex = 1; // пропускаем первую картинку
        var imageCount = images.length;

        function url(index) {
            return 'url(\'/images/my_slider/' + images[index] + '\')';
        }

        bgFade.css({
            opacity: 0,
            backgroundImage: url(imageIndex++)
        }).show();

        function fadeInOut() {

            function animationComplete() {
                if (imageIndex >= imageCount) {
                    imageIndex = 0;
                }

                if (fadeIn) {
                    // сейчас виден затеняющий слой
                    // меняем картинку на фоновом слое
                    bg.css('background-image', url(imageIndex++));
                } else {
                    // сейчас затеняющий слой полностью прозрачен
                    // меняем на нем картинку
                    bgFade.css('background-image', url(imageIndex++));
                }

                fadeIn = !fadeIn;
            }

            bgFade.stop(true, true);
            bgFade.animate({
                opacity: ((fadeIn) ? 1 : 0)
            }, fadeTime, animationComplete);
        }

        /* возвращаем идентификатор таймера, чтобы можно было остановить перебор */
        return setInterval(fadeInOut, period, fadeTime);
    }

    var images = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg'];

    //запускаем перебор картинок
    fadeInOutLoop($('#logo_for_my_slider'), $('#bg_bottom_my_slider'), 1500, 750, images);
});
//если бы этот слой был вверху, то при наведении мыши он бы двигался
$('#logo_for_my_slider').css({
    backgroundPosition: "0 0"
}).mouseover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(-500px 0)"
    }, {
        duration: 5000
    })
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: "(0 0)"
    }, {
        duration: 5000
    })
})
//эта штука работает, потому является верхним слоем
// как сделать так что бы, при наведении на этот слой
// двигались бы и слои слайдшоу?
$('#my_top_slider').css({
    backgroundPosition: 'right 0'
}).mouseover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: 'right -200'
    }, {
        duration: 300
    })
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: 'right 0'
    }, {
        duration: 300
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно повесить прозрачный див поверх всего и ловить rollover события уже с него.

**Добавлено.**

По идее так

```
$('#ВЕРХНИЙ ДИВ').css({
    backgroundPosition: 'right 0'
}).mouseover(function () {
    $("#my_top_slider").stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: 'right -200'
    }, {
        duration: 300
    })
}).mouseout(function () {
    $("#my_top_slider").stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: 'right 0'
    }, {
        duration: 300
    })
})
```

Только не забудьте добавить этот самый "Верхний див", установить его размер и повесить z-index:999

Comment: Я не знаю, как совместить эффект анимации, как  применить это на другие элементы, и что бы это все работало.

Comment: Я как бы так и предполагал сделать, но не знаю как.

Comment: По идее так
$('#ВЕРХНИЙ ДИВ').css({
    backgroundPosition: 'right 0'
}).mouseover(function () {
    $("#my_top_slider").stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: 'right -200'
    }, {
        duration: 300
    })
}).mouseout(function () {
    $("#my_top_slider").stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: 'right 0'
    }, {
        duration: 300
    })
})

Только не забудьте добавить этот самый "Верхний див"

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: Не забывайте принимать ответ ;)

Comment: какая прелесть! только сейчас добрался наконец до этого. это работает с небольшими переделками. и блок .css({}) в начале -- не нужен.
спасибо большое!

Comment: Будь здоров! :)